# Как установить Windows 7 на компьютер в 2022 году?

Tags: windows, windows-7, bios, uefi

У меня есть компьютер (современный).

На него мне для работы одной программы нужно установить `Windows 7`.

При загрузке с установочной флешки `OS` сначала пишет

```
Windows is loading files...
```

а потом пишет

```
Starting windows
```

И всё зависает.

Может можно как-то интегрировать драйвера или ещё что

*без вм

Comment: Не уверен, но, возможно, дело в драйверах USB3.0, которые не поддерживаются Win7 - https://mdex-nn.ru/page/ustanovka-windows-7-usb-30.html

Comment: Вероятнее всего вам нужно менять Жесткий диск, недавно сталкивался с такой проблемой. В итоге сменил жесткий диск и все поправилось. Либо проблема в самой Windows, на новые компы обычно устанавливают новые ОС Windows10, Windows 11

Comment: если для одной программы может лучше VM? VMware Player например

Comment: *На него мне для работы одной программы нужно установить Windows 7.* Если это надо для работы именно ОДНОЙ программы - то почему бы не поставить W7 в виртуалку?

Comment: "*без вм" - аргументируйте, почему это вам не подходит. Пока что это единственный реальный вариант. Ну, еще можно например купить старый б/у ноут с Win7, и запускать эту единственную программу на нем.

Comment: наверное с флешки в режиме UEFI грузитесь, надо разрешить CSM и выбрать в BIOS в списке устройств флешку без UEFI

Comment: @PavelGridin я вангую, что даже если установить получится, то не подтянутся драйвера чипсета, потому что Win7 уже не поддерживается. Будет система, где можно что-то посмотреть, попечатать, пощелкать мышкой (через legacy поддержку usb), но например без доступа к флешкам и интернета.

Comment: @PavelGridin а если csm не поддерживается?

Comment: даже не знаю, режим установки UEFI или MBR определяется тем как загружен установочный диск, если chipset intel, надо у них на сайте смотреть, что ихний пакет драйверов поддерживает